# How can I send an enum value in a form in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-el

I want to pass an *enum* value as defined in the following class over a form:

```
package com.test.entity.common;

public enum RequestStatus {
    PENDING,
    APPROVED,
    REJECTED
}
```

The form:

```
<select th:field="*{selectedRequestType}">
   <option value="${T(com.test.entity.common.RequestStatus).PENDING}">PENDING</option>
   <option value="${T(com.test.entity.common.RequestStatus).APPROVED}">APPROVED</option>
   <option value="${T(com.test.entity.common.RequestStatus).REJECTED}">REJECTED</option>
</select>
```

Why does this return the entire value as the **string literal** `T(com.test.entity.common.RequestStatus).REJECTED` instead of just the **enum** `REJECTED`? Is there a way to do this using SpEL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just

```
<option value="PENDING">PENDING</option>
```

Will be fine. For *enum* type Spring Boot can convert the string to related *enum* automatically.